# How to check if any host trying to connect back to the my executable(application)?

Tags: server, monitoring, backdoor

Last month i have downloaded some hacking tools!!! After that i'm having a strong feeling that some host trying to connect back to the application(don't know whether i'm been monitored or not). Is there any way to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and easiest way would be to verify whether there are processes keeping a socket open for listening.

You need a utility such as `netstat` (Unix, Mac and Windows). There are also GUI utilities - I seem to remember tcpstat and wintcp for Windows. Also Process Explorer by SysInternals and TCPView.

These utilities will provide you with the open ports being used and the process ID of the owning process. You need then to verify whether the process is legit or not, and you can research the port number on Google.

Also, you can run an antivirus/antimalware scan to see whether there are *known* threats active.

And you can do something quick and dirty such as scanning the system for recently changes files (there will be a lot of those), reviewing the changes to determine whether they're legit or not.

On, say, a Windows system, recently created files with executable extensions (.exe, .scr, .com, .dll, .pif, .lnk, .bat, .cmd, .ps1) are a prime suspect unless you know they're harmless. Files such as .htm, .html and .js outside of browser directory are also untrustworthy (unless you're a Web developer and those are *your* files). Recently **changed** files with the same characteristics are also suspicious - a sufficiently advanced virus can easily hide *within* another executable (*and* would probably also reset its modification time and date so you don't notice anything, so while a change *is* suspicious, not detecting any changes is *not* a guarantee unless you have at least a set of trusted file signatures from beforehand, kept in a trusted place, and a trusted way of checking them, e.g. Tripwire Boot CD or USB key. Some level of defense is usually supplied by the operating system in some ways, e.g. Windows has SFC and Linux has AppArmor, but they're far from a silver bullet).

Finally you can monitor system changes with their date (registry keys, initialisation scripts and tasks).

These are quick, relatively easy, and simple approach and probably won't detect more advanced threats such as rootkits and "stealth" viruses. In that case, there are rootkit-detecting utilities too (both from antivirus companies such as ESET, and well known sources such as Rootkit Revealer or rkhunter).

Still *more* advanced threats - packages knowing and actively trying to circumvent rootkit detection strategies - do exist, are not as likely as a straight "open socket and lurk" drop-in trojan horse, and would require considerable knowledge to operate.

--

And that's why you don't just download and run 'hacking applications' on a non-disposable machine without knowing **exactly** what you're doing and/or how to monitor said machine, or are ready to nuke it from orbit afterwards, wiping it clean and reinstalling everything (and even this has a vanishingly small probability - the same of having annoyed NSA, the Mossad or equally easygoing guys - of [not](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/bios-virus-rootkit-security-backdoor,7400.html) being enough. It would have to be a tailored attack, but they do exist).